# How can I convert this SQL Script to LINQ? And keep the Count()?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have made and tested my a MS SQL script that works perfectly. I've been slowly transitioning to LINQ and I am having trouble converting my script into VB.Net and LINQ.

```
SELECT DATEPART(dd,Generated) AS Day, count(ID) as Total
FROM Alarm
WHERE Generated >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0),120)
GROUP BY DATEPART(dd,Generated)
```

Basically, I'm asking the table to give me the total number of rows for the month grouped per day. It would be awesome to have it place a 0 for the future days of the month. Any advice on how to convert count into LINQ would be great.

My code:

```
Dim ChartData = (From a In db.Alarms _
Where a.Generated >= FirstDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) And a.Generated <= LastDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) _
Group By Day = a.Generated Into Grp = Group, Count() _
Select Grp)

'Get the first day of the month
Public Function FirstDayOfMonth(ByVal sourceDate As DateTime) As DateTime
    Return New DateTime(sourceDate.Year, sourceDate.Month, 1)
End Function

'Get the last day of the month
Public Function LastDayOfMonth(ByVal sourceDate As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim lastDay As DateTime = New DateTime(sourceDate.Year, sourceDate.Month, 1)
    Return lastDay.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
End Function
```

Got it working, here is the code.

```
        Dim ChartData = (From a In db.Alarms _
        Where a.Generated >= FirstDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) And a.Generated <= LastDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) _
        Group a By CalendarDate = a.Generated.Value.Date Into g = Group _
        Select New With {CalendarDate, .AlarmCount = g.Count()})
```

Comment: I have and I cannot get it to compile due to syntax issues. Figured I'd ask how people are using count here and learn from that.

Comment: Your `where` is pretty convoluted.  Are you just trying to add 120 months to now?

Comment: then why aren't you posting the code you have and asking for help with the syntax issues?

Comment: My Goal was to get the current day range in the current month.

Comment: Posted my code, but I felt it was misleading to my true goal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this. (I think `dd` means day...`)

```
var myDate = new DateTime(); //calculate your date...
Alarms
    .Where(x => x.Generated >= myDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Generated.Day)
    .Select (x => new {
        Day = x.Key,
        Total = x.Count()
    }
```

You might not be able to group by `x.Generated.Day` in sql, if so, then add `.AsEnumerable()` after the `Where()` to do the grouping in memory.